# I don’t know anyone with Jack’s name / I don’t know anyone whose name is Jack / I don't know anyone named Jack

Tags: phrase-usage

Which one is natural, or are all the ones good? Or is "with Jack’s name" good when it's only about some thing, for example, "an envelope with Jack’s name on it"?

> **I don’t know anyone with Jack’s name.**
>
> **I don’t know anyone whose name is Jack.**
>
> **I don't know anyone named Jack.**

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike examples two and three, the first example indicates that there *is* a Jack, since we use a possessive. I would take it to mean that you don't know a *second* Jack, just like you might say "I don't know anyone with my name" (though obviously you know one person who has it, yourself." That usage is fine, though it might be clearer to add "... anyone *else* with...". The other two examples are perfectly natural. Another to add might be "I don't know anyone *by the name of* 'Jack.'"